# React : How can I store my text file's content into a variable using async->fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

How can I store text file's content to string variable using fetch?
I'm using React.js and my File's content is being read in console, but I cannot seem to store it.

Naturally, TextFile returns me undefined, but I wonder if there is a way to catch a promise and store it permanently in a string var?
Thank you in advance; Marin

```
let TextFile;
    function getFile(){
      return fetch(myText)
        .then((response)=>response.text())
        .then((text)=>console.log(text))
        .then((text)=>TextFile=text)
    }
getFile();
console.log(TextFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use response.text() method in fetchAPI

```
function getData() {
  var myRequest = new Request('abc.txt');
  fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
      myArticle.innerHTML = text;
    });
  });
}
```

for more ref please see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! its working,
Have a great day!

Comment: @Marna can you please vote up and accept the answer.